# SSH port forwarding to reuse restrictive JumpHost ssh connection

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, mobaxterm

I've been browsing through blogs and forum posts, but wouldnt find exactly my problem

At my workplace we have an accessible jumphost: login..com
One can login via ssh and access the internal network from the jumphost.

For my work (robotics related) i got 3 computers and one proxmox host with multiple vm. Some of the vm are directly connected to work lan (10.x.x.x) and some are only accessible from the robotcell (172.31.1.x) itself

The connection through the login server is nice and stable, but ive been asked to reduce the amount of logins. Now, my idea is to open one ssh connection from home to jumphost and reuse that connection and tunnel everything through.

How would one do that?

Unfortunately, im working with windows and got used to one piece of software: Mobaxterm. I could use putty, but if there is a way with Mobaxterm, id prefer that..

It seems that controlhost is not working with Mobaxterm.

**EDIT:
copypasting comment:**

cant install anything on login.* it has to be some kind of connection multiplexing. Instead of opening a ssh session for each connection through login.* i would like to open one and let Putty, MobaXTerm, VSCode reuse that very connection as a tunnel for their ssh connections

Software A wants to connect HOST C jumping through Bastion B
Software B wants to connect HOST D jumping through Bastion B

---

Not possible.. only one connection on B possibel

Wish:

A opens Tunnel to B.
A reuse Tunnel on B to get to C
B reuse Tunnel on B to get to D\

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying out [`byobu`](https://www.byobu.org/)?

This of course requires that `byobu` is available on the jumphost, but if it is you can just open it there and create multiple tabs where you can jump on to other hosts. You can even detach `byobu` so your session is retained even though you log out of the jumphost, and you can log in again and continue where you left off.

Comment: I must admit that I'd wish I could give you a better answer, since I myself have a use case where `byobu` is not ideal, but it may just be at least an improvement for you.

Comment: Please see my edit in Question - put it there for formatting :-)

Comment: @MightyMirko it doesn't really make sense that B should reuse the tunnel to itself.